# How to prove that if $f=g$ a.e. then $\int f = \int g$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I would like to prove the following statement:

> Let $f, g: \Omega \to [- \infty, \infty]$ be two measurable functions such that $f=g$ a.e. Then $\int_{\Omega} f = \int_{\Omega} g$. (I'm not sure if we have to assume that $f, g$ are integrable).

I am able to prove it if $f, g$ have codomain $\mathbb{R}$. We can form $f-g$ which is zero a.e. and therefore integrable with integral zero. Now 
$$\int f = \int((f-g)+g) = \int(f-g) + \int g = \int g$$.

However, I'm not sure how to proceed when the codomain is $[- \infty, \infty]$. I think there is probably a way to do it from the definitions; prove it first for simple functions, then for limits of simple functions, etc. But that has been giving me trouble, and I would like to avoid it if possible anyway.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to assume integrable or non-negative for the integrals to be defined.  Then, the same argument works. If a function is zero a.e., its integral is zero, doesn't matter if it may take the value infinity or even be undefined on a set of measure zero.

Comment: @Thorgott But if the codomain is $[-\infty, \infty]$, it is not safe to write $f-g$, since that is undefined if $f=g=\infty$ at some point.

Comment: My point is that that doesn't really matter. As far as integration is concerned, we only care about functions up to what they do on sets with measure zero. If being undefined bothers you, just define it to be $0$ wherever it's undefined; the integral won't change. This is simply a consequence of the integral of any function over a set of measure zero being zero (which follows from definition).

Answer (score 3):

It is obviously a neccesary assumption that $f$ and $g$ are integrable with respect to some measure $\mu$, and if so then we can compute
\begin{align*}
\int f \: d\mu &= \int_{\{f=g\}} f \: d\mu + \int_{\{f\neq g\}} f \: d\mu \\
       &=\int_{\{f=g\}}g \: d\mu + 0 \\
       &= \int_{\{f=g\}}g \: d\mu + \int_{\{f\neq g\}} g \: d\mu \\
       &= \int g \: d\mu
\end{align*}
where the fact that $\int_{\{f\neq g\}} f \: d\mu= 0 = \int_{\{f\neq g\}} g \: d\mu$ follows from the fact that $\{f\neq g\}$ has measure $0$ by assumption. Technically $\{f\neq g\}$ is not neccesarily measurable in which case we must replace it with a suitable measurable null set $N$ with $\{f\neq g\} \subseteq N$.

Wheter the codomain of $f$ and $g$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$ or $[-\infty,\infty]$ doesn't matter, since integrability of $f$ and $g$ forces $\{f=\infty\},\{f=-\infty\},\{g=\infty\} \text{ and }\{g=-\infty\}$ all to be sets of measure $0$.

Comment: If you assume non-negativity instead of integrability, the same still works, of course.

Comment: yes, in fact it is enough to assume that either $\int f_+ \: d\mu < \infty $ or $\int f_- \: d\mu < \infty$, where $f_+$ and $f_-$ are positive and negative parts.